# Understanding Stress Test Results

Tags: linux, nginx, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04

So I did a stress test on my Wordpress based website running on the cheapest Digital Ocean tier. I am using WP Super Cache for caching on the server end and Nginx as my web server. I am also using Cloudlfare as my CDN and their free SSL throughout my site. I did some testing using loader.io and got the following results. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my server. 
I have looked at the load testing websites understanding results page but I didn't really understand the content.

http://ldr.io/1F45Y9G

I don't really expect to get any traffic on my site, I just wanted to understand how all this stuff works. So what exactly do these performance results mean? What else can I do to optimize my site further?
My site is dikshant.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So what exactly do these performance results mean?*

this means your server can handle a specific amount of users (connections) per second but it will increase the response time of your server. its some kind of denial of service attack to see when is the server going down. when you see the graphs your server can handle ~170 connections per second and the average response time is about 25ms. but it is jumping between 15 ms - 405 ms. all in all you have tested 10.000 connections in a short amount of time and your server had 0 timeouts so its cool. when you increase your incoming connections (clients) per seconds your server responsetime will grow until a point your server cant handle the connections anymore. so its going down.

*What else can I do to optimize my site further?*

you could check which parts are consuming most of your resources. is your server going down because of to much CPU Usage or is your memory not big enough? there are some standard routines to optimize but I guess when you are using wordpress it should be optimized.

rule of the thumb. if you dont have to dont do it.

Comment: What factors contribute to a server not being able to handle more connections? Is it usually the hardware or the software (e.g. your app and the framework you picked - say node)